# Extracting Information Sent Using res.json From a Node + Express API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am building a relatively simple end-point that should return a number after doing a brief database query and a calculation. The problem is that I am uncertain on how I should send it to the front-end, so it is easily accessible there. In particular, I have been using the `res.json()` method, but when `console.log`'ed, it returns a huge object with the data in question nowhere to be found.

How can I go about sending data from API and accepting it on the front end? That is, I assume it will come as JSON, but I am wondering about unpacking it.

Here is the code:

```
router.get('/current/:id', function(req, res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');

    var started = false;
    var seconds;

    //Important to use findOne here to get an object back instead of an array
    collection.findOne({_id : req.params.id }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        var dateNow = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log("activity in /current/:id is: " + activity);
        if (activity.runtime) {
            var dateStart = (Date.parse(activity.runtime.startDate));
            seconds = Math.round((dateNow - dateStart) / 1000);
            started = activity.runtime.started;
            console.log("dateNow: " + dateNow);
            console.log("dateStart " + dateStart);
            console.log("seconds " + seconds);
            console.log(activity.runtime.started);
        } else {
            started = false;
            seconds = 0;
        }

        if (started && (seconds > 0)) {
            //res.json(seconds);
            console.log(res.json(seconds));
        }
        else {
            //res.json(0);
            console.log(res.json(seconds));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to be care of response content, you can send the response in this way :

```
 if (started && (seconds > 0)) {
     console.log(seconds);
     res.send({data : seconds});
 }else {
     res.send({data : 0});
  }
```

and the client will receive the data as:

```
{data : 0}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I am still curious about all the other stuff in there that comes through :-)

Comment: There is no problem, you can send all the responses as the above snippet.